# Image disappears on component re-renders

Tags: image, react-native

I have a functional component that shows a preview of the image or video being uploaded.  I render this conditionally based off a state variable called media:

```
    const renderMediaInPreview = useCallback(() => {
        if(media && media.type === "image") {
            return (
                <Image style={{ height: '100%', aspectRatio: 1, resizeMode: 'cover'}} source={{ uri: media.uri }} />
            )
        } else if(media && media.type === 'video') {
            return (
                <Video 
                    style={{ flex: 1 }}
                    source={{ uri: media.uri }} 
                    isLooping
                    shouldPlay
                    resizeMode={Video.RESIZE_MODE_COVER}
                    isMuted={true}
                />
            )
        }
    }, [media])
```

I've wrapped it in a `useCallback` so the function is only called when the `media` value changes.  However using console logs I am able tto see that whenever the other state of the component is changed this re-runs and even though the `media` value stays the same it make the image disappear.  Any insights?  Below is my return and clip of behavior.

```
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <KeyboardAwareScrollView
                    style={{  flex: 1 }}
                    resetScrollToCoords={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
                    contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center' }}
                    scrollEnabled={true}
                    keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}
                    behavior={Platform.OS == "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
                    removeClippedSubviews={true}
                >

                    { renderErrorMessage() }

                    ... 


                </KeyboardAwareScrollView>                
        </SafeAreaView>

      );
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-fYSOYTP0W86rRaS_CHqWw_gYfZFBcXT/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to track this down and figured out it was not in relation to an issue with `useCallback`. I had done some refactoring of code and `media` was changing slightly that I didn't notice because of the refactor and no longer rendering anything because if didn't match the above `if/then` check.

Minor error that ended up taking a ton of unnecessary time... sigh.